# How to calculate total with Stepper onIncrement and onDecrement

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, stepper

I have the simple add function which can calculate the total . It working fine . I want to update grand total when + and - is clicked form stepper . Not sure How can I pass the total variable into stepper ..

Here is the modal ..

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Welcome
struct ProductData: Codable, Hashable {
    let carts: [Cart]
}

// MARK: - Cart
struct Cart: Codable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    let products: [Product]
}

// MARK: - Product
struct Product: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    var price, quantity, total: Int
    let discountPercentage: Double
    let discountedPrice: Int
    let thumbnail: String
}
```

Here is my class ..

```
import SwiftUI

class Order: ObservableObject {

    @Published var products = [Product]()
    @Published private(set) var productTotal: Int = 0

    func add(item: Product) {
        if let index = products.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == item.id }) {
            products[index].quantity += 1
            productTotal += item.quantity * item.price

        } else {
            products.append(item)
            productTotal += item.quantity * item.price
        }
    }

    func remove(item: Product) {
        if let index = products.firstIndex(of: item) {
            products.remove(at: index)
            productTotal -= item.quantity * item.price
        }
    }
}
```

Be more specific.. Here is the Stepper code ..

```
 VStack {
    HStack {
         Stepper {
           Text("\(Image(systemName: "multiply"))\(item.quantity)")
                      }
                   onIncrement: {
                        item.quantity += 1
                              }
                                onDecrement: {
                                    if item.quantity > 1 {
                                        item.quantity -= 1
                                    }
                                }
                 Image(systemName: "trash")
              .foregroundColor(Color(hue: 1.0, saturation:0.89, brightness: 0.835))
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                    order.remove(item: item)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

Here is the view code for calculating total..

```
             HStack {
                Text("Your cart total is :")
                        .bold()
                    Spacer()
                    Text("£\(order.productTotal).00")
                        .bold()
                }
                .padding()
```

Here is complete  my view code ..

```
import SwiftUI

struct OrderView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var order: Order

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    ForEach.init($order.products) { $item in
                        Section {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Description")
                                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                    .bold()
                                Spacer()
                                Text("Action")
                                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                    .bold()
                            }
                        }

                        HStack {
                            if let url = URL(string: item.thumbnail) {
                                ProductAsyncImageView(url: url)
                                    .frame(width: 90, height: 90)
                                    .padding(.bottom, -10)
                                    .clipShape(Circle())
                            }
                            Spacer()

                            VStack {
                                HStack {
                                    Stepper {
                                        Text("\(Image(systemName: "multiply"))\(item.quantity)")

                                    }
                                onIncrement: {
                                    item.quantity += 1
                                  // increment function 

                                }
                                onDecrement: {
                                    if item.quantity > 1 {
                                        item.quantity -= 1
                                    // decrement function
                                    }
                                }
                                Image(systemName: "trash")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(hue: 1.0, saturation: 0.89, brightness: 0.835))
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                    order.remove(item: item)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            Spacer()
                        }

                        VStack {
                            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                                Text("Name: \(item.title)")
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                    .bold()
                            }
                            HStack {
                                Text("Price: £\(item.price)")
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .bold()
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                Text("Sub Total: £\(item.quantity * item.price)")
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .bold()
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text("Your cart total is :")
                            .bold()
                        Spacer()
                        Text("£\(order.productTotal).00")
                            .bold()
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
                Section {
                    NavigationLink("Place Order") {
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Order")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to add a function to your model - Also, an `Int` probably isn't a good choice for representing currency.  [`NSDecimalNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdecimalnumber) is best, but for simplicity we can use a `Double`.

```
class Order: ObservableObject {

    @Published var products = [Product]()
    @Published private(set) var productTotal: Double = 0

    func add(item: Product) {
        if let index = products.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == item.id }) {
            products[index].quantity += 1
  
        } else {
            products.append(item)
        }
        self.calculateTotal()
    }

    func remove(item: Product) {
        if let index = products.firstIndex(of: item) {
            products.remove(at: index)
            self.calculateTotal()
      
        }
    }

    func calculateTotal() {
        self.productTotal = self.products.reduce(0.0, { total, item in 
            total+Double(item.quantity)*item.price
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use this function when you increment or decrement an item quantity:

```
Stepper {
    Text("\(Image(systemName: "multiply"))\(item.quantity)")
}
onIncrement: {
    item.quantity += 1
    self.order.calculateTotal()
}

onDecrement: {
    if item.quantity > 1 {
        item.quantity -= 1
        self.order.calculateTotal()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you mentioned to use decimal, currently I am getting values like this 89.000000.00 . How can I display only two digit after the doth ? Ideally this is correct way to display the values

Comment: Use `Text("Price: ")+Text(item.price.formatted(.currency(code:"GBP)))`

Comment: Sorry One more things How can we pass the format function on this text Text("Sub Total:\(item.quantity * item.price)") ?

Comment: I would add a computed property to your item `var subtotal: Double: { Double(self.quantity*self.price)}` and then you can use `Text(item.subtotal.formatted(.currency(code:"GBP")))`

Comment: with computed property I can not access the products properties..var subtotal: Double {
        return Double(self.products.quantity*self.products.price)

    }

Comment: I got error No exact matches in call to initializer .. Value of type '[Product]' has no member 'price'

Comment: if you look at the order class and I have added the model

Answer (score 1):

Your `productTotal` should be a computed property. Change your `Order` class to this and it should work:

```swift
class Order: ObservableObject {
    @Published var products = [Product]()
    var productTotal: Int {
        products.map { $0.quantity * $0.price }.reduce(0, +)
    }

    func add(item: Product) {
        if let index = products.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == item.id }) {
            products[index].quantity += 1
        } else {
            products.append(item)
        }
    }

    func remove(item: Product) {
        if let index = products.firstIndex(of: item) {
            products.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A computed property won't work, because it won't trigger a view refresh

Comment: @Paulw11 Just checked online and you're right, if `Product` isn't a value type then my code won't work. Hopefully Nus has coded `Product` as a struct.